# How to use readLine() unknown multiple times?

Tags: swift

How to read an unknown number of rows in advance while using `readLine()`?

I don't know, how many string user will provide me. I tried this, but in vain:

```swift
var commands = [String]()

for _ in 0..<Int(pow(Double(5), Double(5))) {
    if let readLine = readLine() {
        commands.append(readLine)
    } else {
        break
    }
}

print(commands) // this code is unreachable, even after 25 lines were provided
```

#### Example 1:

Input:

```
asd
asdasd
123
```

Output:

```swift
commands = ["asd", "asdasd", "123"]
```

#### Example 2:

Input:

```
asd
asdasd
asdasdasd
123
asd
```

Output:

```swift
commands = ["asd", "asdasd", "asdasdasd", "123", "asd"]
```

Comment: The criteria is that there is no more input, yes. I've added example to the question

Comment: Please, read the examples properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `readLine()`, your program will read from standard input until either a newline is encountered, or the end of standard input has been reached. As such, a construction like

```swift
var commands = [String]()
while let line = readLine() {
    commands.append(line)
}

// No more input; do something with `commands`.
```

will read as many lines as there is input and return them to you one at a time, until input is done.

It's important to understand what this means for the user of your program, though. In the Unix philosophy, [everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file), including standard input; this means that interactions with input and output always have an interface that makes it look like you're reading from, or writing to a file. `readLine()` will return input until it hits EOF, or End-Of-File, an indicator that there is no more data to be read from the file. This feels natural for a file, which has an actual end, but when a user is running your program interactively from the command line and typing in commands themselves, there *is* no file. How does `readLine` know when the user will be done typing?

The answer is that the user will need to manually indicate "I am done typing; send the EOF marker to standard input" by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in the terminal. How and why this works is out of scope for this question, but [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177662/173357) from the Unix StackExchange gives some details.

From the user's perspective, they will need to type in commands one line at a time, and when they are done, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on their keyboard to send your `readLine()` an `EOF`, at which point it will return `nil` and exit out of the loop.

This may be expected, or it may be unexpected. For instance, this is typically how REPLs work: if you go to the command line and run `swift`, you will get an interactive session, which will run your input line by line. When you are done, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit. (Swift also recognizes specific commands to exit, such as `:q[uit]`, which will work as well.) But, REPLs also give feedback line-by-line as you run commands; it might be a *little* different for the user to have all of their input collected up-front with no feedback at all, then processed entirely once they hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.